# Xpages. Using Java

Tags: java, xpages

I'd like to apologize if my question doesn't sound very much specific, but i do believe (and i've seen it already from the answers) that there are people here who will be able to help me in my rather general problem.
Besides, i have a feeling that this is not only my problem but for many Domino Developers it would be of great benefit to get the answers for the following question(s).

That's being said, the question/problem is -> 
I'd like to use Java in XPages. I'm no way a profi in Java but do know the basics and have pretty good understanding of OOP and OOD.

Therefore the general question is -> how and where do i start in Domino XPages universe in order to develop the new skills as the Java developer ?

More specific one -> am i right, thinking that the beginning point could be start using Java in form of JavaBeans in order to describe the M (Model) layer in MVC architecture?

I would be very thankfull for some easy pieces of Java code and short explanations how to use them. Also some good links will be accepted as the help :)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Comment: Brian, good point. I do recognize that this my perticular question isn't 100 % "stackoverflow" question (probably even much less then 100). On the other side i'm also 100 % sure that there will be many people who will profit out of the answers and will get at the end a bit happier :) Probably the best way would be is to let the people decide. If they like it -> they will upvote, if they don't -> well, my fresh reputation will suffer some points. Finally, my intentions are good, so i act.

Comment: Check out Samir Pipalia's blog at www.pipalia.co.uk/tag/mvc-2/ there is an excellent series on called Rethinking XPages about using MVC with Java beans in Xpages.  It sounds exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's http://XPages.tv is THE place to start. You then want to head over to http://xpages.info and check my [summary page](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/Learning-XPages) for more learning (it is not a tutorial but sends you to all the right places).

Comment: Actually it should be "David's http://XPages.TV".  :)  Many XPages and Java related videos are located there.  They're originally from NotesIn9.com.

Comment: @DavidLeedy - sorry for that. Fixed it

Answer (score 9):

I've got a series of videos on beginnIng to use java in xpages over at http://xpages.tv that discuss setting up the NSF for java dev as well as how to write and implement managed beans etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found :

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Master_Table_of_Contents_for_XPages_Extensibility_APIs_Developer_Guide

very useful in learning the basics of creating controls in java